# MoneyField isChanged always returning true

Tags: silverstripe

I have a `DataObject` `Confirmation` that looks like this:

```
<?php

class Confirmation extends DataObject
{

    private static $db = array(
        'Reimbursement' => 'Money',
        'SomeText'      => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Page'  => 'Page'
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {

        $fields             = parent::getCMSFields();
        $reimbursementField = MoneyField::create('Reimbursement');
        $someTextField      = TextField::create('SomeText');

        $reimbursementField->setAllowedCurrencies(array('SEK'));

        $fields->addFieldsToTab(
            'Root.Main',
            array(
                $reimbursementField,
                $someTextField
            )
        );

        return $fields;

    }

    public function onBeforeWrite()
    {
        parent::onBeforeWrite();
        if($this->isChanged('Reimbursement')) SS_Log::log( print_r ( 'changed', true ), SS_Log::WARN );
    }

}
```

`if($this->isChanged('Reimbursement'))` in the `onBeforeWrite()` function will always evaluate to `true`. Regardless of what is being changed. Even when saving without making any changes - it will fire the log function.

Edit: Checking the stacktrace with `SS_Backtrace::backtrace()` in `Money.php`'s `setValue()` function I find that every time I save the `Confirmation` `DataObject`, `setValue()` is called without passing the `$markChanged` parameter set to false, from `DataObject.php line 1281`, resulting in the `$isChanged` flag being set to `true`, and the field always behaving as if it has changed.

When logging `DataObject`'s `getChangedFields()` function I get the output below (when saving without making any changes). Notice the Reimbursement field being present, and `before` being empty. What am I missing here?

```
[22-Mar-2016 16:28:07] Warning at framework/model/DataObject.php line 2597: Array
(
    [Reimbursement] => Array
        (
            [before] => 
            [after] => Money Object
                (
                    [currency:protected] => SEK
                    [amount:protected] => 25000
                    [isChanged:protected] => 1
                    [locale:protected] => 
                    [currencyLib:protected] => Zend_Currency Object
                        (
                            [_options:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [position] => 8
                                    [script] => 
                                    [format] => 
                                    [display] => 2
                                    [precision] => 2
                                    [name] => svensk krona
                                    [currency] => SEK
                                    [symbol] => kr
                                    [locale] => sv_SE
                                    [value] => 0
                                    [service] => 
                                    [tag] => Zend_Locale
                                )

                        )

                    [allowedCurrencies:protected] => 
                    [value:protected] => 
                    [tableName:protected] => 
                    [name:protected] => Reimbursement
                    [arrayValue:protected] => 
                    [defaultVal:protected] => 
                    [failover:protected] => 
                    [customisedObject:protected] => 
                    [objCache:ViewableData:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [class] => Money
                    [extension_instances:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [beforeExtendCallbacks:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [afterExtendCallbacks:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [level] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: It could be a dodgy relationship between your Confirmation and Money models - can you share their relationships?

Comment: @RobbieAverill Thank you. I sandboxed the problem and posted the entire `DataObject` - please see the updated question.

Comment: @Janne Klouman You are right, Money::isChanged is always set to true. Try using `$confirmation->ReimbursementAmount` and `$confirmation->ReimbursementCurrency` for original database values.

Comment: Yeah I ended up checking `$this->Reimbursement->getAmount() !== self::get()->byID($this->ID)->Reimbursement->getAmount()` to see if the field is changed.